# magento headers already sent in mage.php

Tags: php, magento, header

I tried to install a caching module in my magento and pasted some code (to enable backend cache) to my local.xml now I get these errors.

```
There has been an error processing your request
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in Mage.php, line 767
Trace:

0 /home1/devirona/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(32045): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->setConnection(false)
1 /home1/devirona/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(24081): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
2 /home1/devirona/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(24113): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
3 /home1/devirona/public_html/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
4 /home1/devirona/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(5861): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
5 /home1/devirona/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(5866): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
6 /home1/devirona/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20959): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
7 /home1/devirona/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20817): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
8 /home1/devirona/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20700): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
9 /home1/devirona/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
10 /home1/devirona/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
11 {main}
```

I tried undoing what I did but all in vain.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Core
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2008 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
-->
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Tue, 02 Sep 2014 14:04:20 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[asdasdasda]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[dv_]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[devirona]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[*********]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[devirona_store]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
        
 
  <cache>
   <backend>Netzarbeiter_Cache_Model_Symlink</backend>
   <backend_options>
    <cache_dir>var/cache</cache_dir>
    <hashed_directory_level>1</hashed_directory_level>
    <hashed_directory_umask>0777</hashed_directory_umask>
    <file_name_prefix>mage</file_name_prefix>
   </backend_options>
  </cache>
 
        
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

this is my local.xml

i cant find what is causing this error..
i added the cache code. first i added it after the closing of config... then i changed it.. before placing the code back inside config i saved it and try to run it then i got the problem

Comment: 1. Use version control. 2. This error is thrown when there is output before the headers are sent.

Comment: thanks guyT... can you please explain what to do as i am new in magento...

Comment: @GuyT thanks for the pointer... next time i will be more careful...baptism by fire i think so..

Comment: glad it is solved :)

Comment: Its not solved still bugging

Comment: download a new `Mage.php`(or the file that you've edited) and overwrite the current file.

Comment: I did that too still the same...

Comment: i deleted the local.xml and surprisingly when i went to my site address it was still showing the same error... so i think the error is somewhere else...

Comment: Thanks guys its solved it was a problem of cash I downloaded a new mage file that too helped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try disabling the compiler by going to /includes/config.php and commenting out the following lines:

```
define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Then try refreshing the cache (by deleting the var/cache directory) and see if it helps.

Comment: i disabled the compiler and then cleared the cache.. still the same.. i can access my site by devirona/index.php... if i try with devirona.com it still showing the same error..

Comment: This issue is usually caused when you have some text which is being outputted before the headers are sent. Ensure that you removed all the debug "echos"/"print_f"s and "var_dumps" (if you added some).

Comment: I see that the local.xml is missing the `</config>` closing tag. Maybe that causes the issue?

Comment: And maybe this class `Netzarbeiter_Cache_Model_Symlink` contains some echos?

Comment: Local.xml was fine... the code I copied missed it... and class netzarbeiter_cache_model_symlink was fine it was in mage I downloaded a new mage and cleared all the cache... then it worked.... thanks a lot for your help... appreciate it...